# Creating a streaming proxy

Tags: php

I use a small PHP proxy for streaming video files. How do I change the script so that playback in browser starts before the file is fully downloaded?

PHP 5 and Apache 2

```
    $url = "http://someremoteserver.com/V12.mp4";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch,
        [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 90
        ]
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($curl, $header)
        {
            header($header);
            return strlen($header);
        }
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($curl, $body)
        {
            echo $body;
            return strlen($body);
        }
    );
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
```

I would like the playback in the browser to start after a few seconds. But it starts only after the file is fully downloaded.